# How can the same TCP port show in netstat as BOUND and ESTABLISHED in Windows?

Tags: windows, networking, tcp, netstat

I'm investigating an issue of port exhaustion in Windows, and the output of netstat shows many ports both as BOUND and ESTABLISHED

```
...
TCP    10.0.1.9:64318         10.0.1.9:8400          ESTABLISHED     10348
...
TCP    0.0.0.0:64318          0.0.0.0:0              BOUND           10348
...
```

How could that happen ?

Update: from my understanding BOUND is a transitory state for a socket, that normally should not appear in netstat's output (and in fact it almost never appears).

In the example above there's an established connection between 2 programs in the same machine.

Port 8400 is bound to a listening socket in the server program.
Port 64318 is bound (by the system) to a connected socket in the client program.

I can see no logical explanation for how can port 64318 also show up as a BOUND socket.

But it does.

Answer (score 2):

[netstat output](http://schweitzeraaron.blogspot.com/2012/07/to-understand-why-netstat-show.html) describes it very well. Basically, an ephemeral port brought up for a connection then removed from the listening state once a connection has been established.